# Vue JS - Unit test - localstorage is not defined

Tags: unit-testing, local-storage, mocha.js, chai, vue-cli-3

I'm writing unit test for for vue cli 3 using Mocha and chai. I have tried mocking localstorage. but still getting this error - 'localStorage is not defined'. Can anyone please help me here?

My code is like this -

```
import { expect, assert } from 'chai';
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import LoginComponent from '@/views/LoginComponent.vue';
import Constants from '@/constants';

declare var global: any;
let wrapper;
let componentInstance: any;
let authData;
var mockLocalStorage = {
  getItem(key: any) {
    if (key === 'access_token') { return '/* a token object */'; }
    return 'null';
  }
};

describe('LoginComponent.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.window = { localStorage: mockLocalStorage };

    authData = JSON.stringify(Constants.AUTH_DATA);

    wrapper = shallowMount(AliUMSLoginComponent, {
      propsData: { authData }
    });
    componentInstance = wrapper.vm;
  });

  it('has a created hook', () => {
    assert.isNotNull(componentInstance.authData);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who might stumble upon this question - the following worked for me:

**1)** Create a `setup.js` file in your unit test folder and add the following code:

```
require('jsdom-global')();

global.localStorage = window.localStorage;
```

After fixing the *"localStorage is undefined"* error, you might experience additional errors (like I did). In the end the following code snippet fixed everything:

```
require('jsdom-global')(undefined, { url: 'https://localhost' });

global.localStorage = window.localStorage;
global.sessionStorage = window.sessionStorage;
window.Date = Date;
```

... You can find more info on this here: [vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2128](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2128) and here: [vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/936](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/936)

**2)** Update the test script in your `package.json` file to load the setup file you just created:

`"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --require tests/unit/setup.js"`

Answer (score 0):

I got your solution to work however when trying to grep for one file to run, it runs all files.

1. Is there a better way to include this maybe with an include at the top of the file? An include usually has a method that returns something.  hmmmm how to do this?
2. Is this the correct syntax for the package.json file:

```
"test:unit-filter": "vue-cli-service test:unit --require tests/unit/helpers/setup.js --watch --grep"
```